# Passing Parameters created in Job A to Job B in MultiJob Phase

Tags: jenkins

I have a MultiJob in which Job A that uses Groovy Script in PostBuild to parse the value and places that in a parameter. Now, I need to pass this parameter to Job B so it can be used in the job. I've tried Predefined Parameters but Job B doesn't seem to capture the parameter from Job A.

I've tried this using Parameterized Trigger Plugin but I would like to try it through MultiJob which runs the jobs sequentially.

Comment: In you MultiJob ,  environment variables created in the parent job  are accessible to all child jobs. So create the env_variables there.

Comment: Make sure same variable/build parameters names are used in both jobs